ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.keyvault' - Azure pipeline run
I am trying to run few ML scripts using Azure pipeline on Azure ML studio. I have created a new ML environment with all the required dependencies as well but am facing a issue as below.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.keyvault'.
Things I have tried till now

created a new environment with all the reqd dependencies.
modified another exisiting environment and added my dependencies there and used it to run my pipeline
In my project yaml file, I have also added a step called pip install azure-keyvault-secrets in the script section.

Somehow the module azure-keyvault-secrets couldnt be found by my code even though it is the same environment. Please help
My Azure env's conda.yml file is as below
channels:
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.8.13
  - pip:
      - azureml-defaults~=1.51.0
      - azureml-dataprep[pandas]
      - azure-storage-blob
      - pyarrow
      - xlrd
      - openpyxl
      - pyyaml
      - tqdm
      - catboost
      - pickle-mixin
      - azure-keyvault-secrets
  - scikit-learn
  - ipykernel
  - matplotlib
  - pandas
  - pip
  - xlrd
  - joblib
  - tqdm
  - time
name: project_ml


Which version of Python are you using in your ML environment?

@BrightRan-MSFT - i am using  python=3.8.13

Try to upgrade to the latest Python 3.12. @ssuhas76

Python 3.8 is the minimum Python version supported by the package azure-keyvault-secrets (see here). However, Python 3.8 is a quite older version and might have problem when running with the latest version of azure-keyvault-secrets.
You can try to upgrade the Python version to the latest Python 3.12, then try the module again in your project.
In Azure DevOps pipelines, you can use the UsePythonVersion@0 task to install a specified Python version.
variables:
  PythonVersion: '3.12'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Install Python v$(PythonVersion)'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(PythonVersion)'

- script: |
    pip install azure-keyvault-secrets
  displayName: 'Install module azure.keyvault'

In addition, you also can use pip to install the package "azure-keyvault", it installs the following packages for Azure Key Vault:

azure-keyvault-keys v4.x
azure-keyvault-secrets v4.x
azure-keyvault-certificates v4.x


